# Can I extend the operators that LINQ-to-SQL supports?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, extension-methods

If I wanted to badly enough, could I add additional LINQ constructs to LINQ-to-SQL (as I would be able to if creating my own LINQ provider)?  For instance, many of the built-in LINQ operators (`XYZ.Any()`) get directly translated to SQL (e.g. `IF EXISTS(XYZ)`).

If I needed a specialized construct, would I even be able to augment the set, or does this have to be baked into the actual LINQ-to-SQL provider?

How would I go about adding a new operator implementation?  Are C# extension methods enough of a hook to do the job?

If the answer is yes, would someone so inclined be able to replace much (all?) of sproc capability via the dynamic SQL generated by LINQ-to-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could add support for arbitrary expressions to a LINQ provider, but Pavel is correct that LINQ to SQL would not work as a starting point. I would look into SubSonic or NHibernate, which also have LINQ providers under development. Once the provider supports an expression, you would just need to build an equivalent extension method on `IQueryable<T>` - reflect `System.Linq.Queryable` for details.

That said, parsing expression trees is definitely not for the faint of heart. Unless you're really interested in AST theory, it would probably be easier to just extend an OSS ORM in a "normal" way.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with what it would take from the AST parsing / expression tree end of things. I actually don't have an exact need yet but was mostly just wondering for future usage. It's too bad as it would be a really cool model if *everything* could be expressed in LINQ. Now when you mention SubSonic & NHibernate, is that because they *do* allow extension or just as another provider which may have what I am needing?

Comment: I'm not aware of any in-built expression extensibility for SubSonic or NHibernate, but at least you have the option to download the source and add your own. As cool as it would be to express _everything_ in LINQ, there are some SQL constructs that simply don't map well. That may change with the extended Expression support in .NET 4.

Answer (score 1):

No, LINQ to SQL is not extensible like that. The best you can do is to use stored procedures.